# React-router remove url with History api

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using react-router@1.0.0-rc1 and I cant get rid of the #/?_k=jg0dw5 on the end of my url. I have looked at other examples and they tell me to do it this way:

```
var createBrowserHistory = require('history/lib/createBrowserHistory');
var routes = (
    <Router createElement={createElement} history={createBrowserHistory()}>
        <Route path='/' component={App} />
        <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
        <Route path='*' component={NotFound}/>
    </Router>
);

ReactDOM.render(routes, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Doing it this way removes the url but I cant access any of my pages since I have added it. Have I missed something out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look here: [Caveats of Using Hash History](https://github.com/rackt/history/blob/master/docs/HashHistoryCaveats.md#caveats-of-using-hash-history)

You should pass a `{ queryKey: false }` parameter to the createHashHistory function.

Comment: <Router createElement={createElement} history={createBrowserHistory({ queryKey: false})}> - I added it in and my pages still dont display. :(

Comment: Try to use it instead: 

`import createHashHistory from 'history/lib/createHashHistory';`

and change `createBrowserHistory` to `createHashHistory`

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you :)

Comment: It now just have the # sign, how do I get rid of that to?

Comment: Then you should use: `import { createHistory } from 'history';`, then just use `history={createHistory()}`

Comment: I stuck with the has way because the import way breaks it again.